# acf() Function plots very large lags

Tags: r, advanced-custom-fields, fgarch

In order to define which Garch Model I should use I tried using the acf function on my daily returns.

I used the following code:

```
    acf.pax=acf(pax_daily_return,main='ACF PAX',lags.max = 12, ylim=c(- 0.5,1))
```

However, when I plot it my y axes ranges from -0.4 to 0.8 and my lags range from **0 to 2500000.**

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have expanded comment and moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The X axis is time, not lags. For example, suppose we measure time in seconds and there is an observation every 3 days.  Then we have the following where frequency is the reciprocal of deltat.  (Try passing ts(pax_daily_return) to acf.)

```
pax_daily_return <- ts(1:20, deltat = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60)

deltat(pax_daily_return)  # seconds between observations
## [1] 259200

frequency(pax_daily_return)  # samples per second
## [1] 3.858025e-06

acf(pax_daily_return, main = 'ACF PAX', lag.max = 12, ylim = c(-0.5, 1))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! But I really need the X axis to show the lags 0  to 10 or 20... Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please read the answer again. It already answers that question.